# I get an exception when I try to get the version of the assembly when the application is published

Tags: c#, maui

I have an Android MAUI application and I would like to get the assembly version. So I use this code:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fvi = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string miStrVersionEnsamblado = fvi.FileVersion;
```

When I debug this application in the device, it works, but when I create the apk publishing it and I install it in the device, the application quits.

I get the exception:
`android.runtime.javaProxyThrowable:Syste.IO.FileNotFoundException:/MyApplication.dll at   System.Diagnostics.FilveVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(string)`

How could I know the version of the application at runtime when I publish the application?

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/version-tracking

Comment: This is a known issue, as you see here.
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/7519

As you develop for android you should also Tag this.

And as the Person above me already mentioned -> essentials.UseVersionTracking() Is the right way of tracking, first launch, version etc...

Comment: Glad you solved it! You could post an answer here, which may help others with similar questions.

Comment: @jason, it is  your answer, if you post an answer, I would give you the answer. Thanks so much.